# ModelBuilder Select Table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table

I'm working on a project where I am building a tool to use. I have a large data set in a standalone table that has data for multiple years and multiple species. The first step in my tool is to make a way that the user just inputs what year and species they want and it will create a new table with just that information that I can then join to the spatial layer. I'm having trouble creating this first step. I have been reading around and I feel like it has to do with Python and the WHERE clause, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: are you wanting to do this with python or with model builder?  You should be able to use model builder with a couple of parameters to enter year and species and have table to table or similar output just the records that match the specified values.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to do it with model builder and I tried to do the parameter thing, but the only way I was able to do that was to specify which species and which year myself instead of the user being able to choose (i.e. YEAR = 2012 everytime). My supervisor mentioned Python which is why I mentioned that. I am extremely new to GIS so sorry if my explanations are confusing about what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

Open Model Builder from ArcMap.

**Tool 1 in Model Builder:**

From the Toolbox, drag in "[Select Layer by Attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//001700000071000000)" tool.  Its under "Data Management".  Right click on the tool and hover over "Make Variable", then when more options pop out, select "From Parameter". When more options pop out select "Input Layer".  When a new circle appears, right click on it and select "Model Parameter".

Right click again on Select Layer by Attribute tool and make another variable by parameter.  This time select the "Expression" pop out.  When a new circle appears, right click on it and select "Model Parameter".

Double click on the tool and under the Selection Type, insert "NEW_SELECTION".  It might be a drop down, can't remember as I don't have software in front of me at the moment.

Your first tool is complete! Yippie!

**Tool 2 in Model Builder:**

Now you need to insert the tool that will make the new table. From the toolbox, drag in the [Table to Table Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Table_to_Table/001200000027000000/).  Its under "Conversion Tools".  Connect the output of the Select Layer by Attribute tool into this tool.  You do this by clicking on the "link" button on the toolbar of Model Builder. Its to the left of the play button.  When you drag the output, it will ask which variable you want to connect to, so select "Input Rows" (or whatever pops out that is close to that).

As you did in tool 1, make variables from the parameters of "Output Path" and "Output Name'.  Right click, Make Variable, from parameter and chose the parameter.  On each new circle, right click and select "Model Parameter".

Right click on output of the Table to Table tool and select "Add to Map".

**Use the tool**

We are done with these tools.  Click the save button and save model in a toolbox when the window pops up.  Create a new toolbox in this window if you don't currently have one and put it somewhere your users can find it.  Close the model.

Navigate to the model inside the Catalog window of Arcmap and double click it.  What pops up should be a window with 4 input parameters, one for your main table, one for your expression, and for your output paths and new table names.  For the expression it will be something similar to "YEAR = 2012 and SPECIES = 'TIGER'".  That's assuming year is an integer field and species is a string field.  YEAR and SPECIES are field names in your table.  If YEAR is a string, then it is like this "YEAR = '2012'.

This is assuming that your table is in your ArcMap Table of Contents.  The Output Path parameter has to be a Workspace, such as a file geodatabase.  The table name should be a string of some type.  If you want to automate the table name, that can be shown later.

Note:  If the tool does not add the new table to the Table of contents, the user can simply navigate to the output path specified in the catalog window and drag it in from there.